# Is there any way to click the button in jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

`button.trigger('click');` doesn't seem to work.

There's also no trigger method in the docs.

Is the only way to set the classes manually?

Thanks.

Edit:

Oh actually not specific enough in asking, sorry. My button is a radio.

Comment: Use the mouse, or tab to the button and hit Return :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `$('#thebutton').click();` but it is important to note that does not simulate a browser-level click; it only invokes any jQuery-assigned click handlers for that button. Anything added outside of the jQuery sandbox will be ignored.

Comment: the OP's `.trigger('click');` did not work... what's the difference with your `$('#thebutton').click();` then?

Comment: @Reigel there is no difference... I'm just explaining what it actually does to hopefully help explain the seemingly-confusing behaviour.

Comment: How does jquery ui attach the active classes? Shouldn't it also work by triggering?

Answer (score 2):

That should work... There is no no trigger method in the docs of jQuery UI simply because it's still the same on how you do it normally on jQuery. I mean the following codes can demonstrate it to you.. see also demo.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs6cX/)

## html

```
<div class="demo">

    <button>A button element</button>

    <input type="submit" value="A submit button"/>

    <a href="#">An anchor</a>

</div><!-- End demo -->


<button id="trigger">Trigger Submit button click</button>​
```

## jQuery

```
$(function() {
    // make button()
    $("button, input:submit, a", ".demo").button().click(function(){
        alert('from button() : I was triggered!');
    });

    // add click handler..
    $('input:submit').click(function(){
        alert('a submit button being triggered');
    });

    // prevent default operation of an anchor
    $("a", ".demo").click(function() { return false; });

    // trigger click on submit button
    $('#trigger').click(function(){
        $('input:submit').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that my button is a radio. I guess that's what makes the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/Qs6cX/2/

Comment: it's still the same... Well, I guess you are not that clear on what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: well if you click on a radio it clearly looks like the radio was selected, that does not happen by triggering in js.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed jQuery need some time to attach the event handler with the button..

so with this:

```
window.setTimeout( function(){
   jQuery("#thebutton").trigger("click");
}, 10 );
```

you should be fine ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Just refer to the actual element instead of the jQuery object.

So the syntax would be: `$('#thebutton')[0].click();`.